# Column layout without fixed widths

Tags: css, css-float

I want to do something really basic -- a two column layout where the width of of the left column is determined by the content (which is always small), and the right column takes the remaining width.

The full example is at http://jsfiddle.net/EzHVX/2/, but basically I have HTML as follows::

```
<div class="left">
   <div class="badge">all 15</div>    
</div>

<div class="right">
   <div class="badge">...</div>
   <div class="badge">...</div>    
  ....
</div>
```

and essential part of CSS is just::

```
.left {
    float: left;
}    

.right {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Without explicit width, the right column starts to wrap around the left column, which I don't want. But I also don't want to use explicit width. And CSS does not support "100% - 10em" as width. And even if it supported it, I'd rather not hardcode "10em" either. So what options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow:hidden`; to the right div will do the job

have updated the link you gave please let know if this works for you

http://jsfiddle.net/EzHVX/4/

Comment: You're supposed to post your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzHVX/4/) then, it's a neat solution :)

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work just as I wanted. I've looked at docs for 'overflow' and honestly can't figure out why it helps. I though it only determines that happens to content when it's already too big for container. So what's the magic here?

Comment: have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow , this should clear your doubt

Comment: Thanks. I also found http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ that explains this.

Comment: Also, it seems that "position: static" for .right is not necessary, as it's the default anyway. Nor is "position: relative" for .left seems necessary, since no positioning is applied. The minimal CSS I can come with is at http://jsfiddle.net/EzHVX/8/

Answer (score 0):

You could use some table-layout CSS properties to accomplish this, works down to and including IE8:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzHVX/5/)

```
body > div {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.badge {
    background-color: #468847;
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding: 2px 9px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.left {
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flex](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) layout to implement (older IE does not support this.)

```
    display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;     /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */     
    display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/EzHVX/7/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
     <div class="badge">all 15</div>    
  </div>

  <div class="right">
     <div class="badge">...</div>
     <div class="badge">...</div>    
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.parent{
   widht: 100%;
   clear:both;
}
.clear{
   clear:both;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}    

.right {
    float: left;
}
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parent_width= $('.parent').width();
    var left_width= $('.left').width();
    var right_width = parseInt(parent_width) - parseInt(left_width);
    $('.right').css('max-width',right_width);

});
```